# How find g(x) to apply the method of Accept-Reject

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I need to apply the method of Accept-Reject to generates data from the random variable X with pdf $f(x) = 0.5*e^{(-√x)}, x>0.$, but It's difficult to me find the function $g(x)$ whith $U \sim U[0,1]$ such that $f(x)/g(x) \leq c$. Any idea to find $g(x)$?
Is there a way to do this ?
thanks.

Comment: What is the intended point of mentioning $U$ and that it is uniform on $[0,1]$? $U$ doesn't appear anywhere else

Comment: yes, $ g(x)$  uniform on $[0,1]$